# Alternative to ZAM 3D editor for Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

I'm looking for some **3D editor** that allows to create 3D objects and **export them to XAML** 
format. Because I'm under **Windows Seven** ZAM 3D editor is no option for me.

I need to create relatively simple(but good looking) 3D objects, no game animations. I prefer **simple and intuitive GUI**, so Blender is no option for me...
It would be good if the program had free trial.

Any ides what might help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running it under Windows 7 backwards compatibility mode?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Blender, you can use the [Xaml exporter for 3D Studio Max](http://max2xaml.codeplex.com/).  It's primitive, but may work for simple models.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want using Zam 3D on Windows 7 ???

I'm using Zam 3D and Swift3D on all my computers, even the big one under Windows 7 / 64 bit with no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your model to the OBJ-format and import it using "Blend for Visual Studio 2013".

In Blend you must add the obj-file using "Project -> Add Existing Item ...".

Then you can drag and drop it in the designer window.
Here you will get the "Viewport3D" containing the camera and the objects:

```
<Viewport3D ClipToBounds="True" Margin="355,200,177,150">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="45" FarPlaneDistance="16700.081028976383" LookDirection="0,0,-5566.69367632546" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" Position="0,-227.324999392032,5566.69367632546" UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="World">
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="AmbientLightContainer">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <AmbientLight x:Name="AmbientLight" Color="#FF7F7F7F"/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="DirectionalLightContainer">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight x:Name="DirectionalLight" Color="#FF3F3F3F" Direction="0,0,-1">
                            <DirectionalLight.Transform>
                                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetZ="3" OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0"/>
                            </DirectionalLight.Transform>
                        </DirectionalLight>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Object1">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <GeometryModel3D x:Name="DefaultMaterial" d:Bounds="-1844.64001464844,-455.779998779297,0,3689.28002929688,456.909998774529,0">
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1
0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1
0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 
...
```