# Display 3D object in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have project that build in **C# WPF**. There is requirement from the client to display 3D object in the app (.obj, .fbx ect... ) and I get to choose the format I will get the object in. So I have started to look at [**helixtoolkit**](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) by did not found any tutorial about how to start working with it, what do I do with the dll files and general how I start. Do you have maybe other API or something simple that I can use?

Comment: Please refere to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127753/displaying-3d-models-in-wpf) article.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying 3D models in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127753/displaying-3d-models-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple look carefully on the [HelixToolKit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/). you can find the [documentation](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation) under [documantation](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation) tab.

http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: The documentation is under construction