# Integration of XNA game with 3D model in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, xna-4.0

We are trying to develop a Virtual dressing room using kinect. We need add movement to the dress according to the persons skeleton point. I found some similar process http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230540/Animating-single-bones-in-a-Blender-3D-model-with#SkinningSampleProject132

I need to embed this into a wpf control. For the I found some article related to my problem http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2011/03/25/wpf-hosting-for-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx But in this they have just created and displayed the animation but there is no clue to embed a 3d model added game, inside a WPF; or else I couldn't the point I don't know.

So, Is there any another way to add a XNA game with 3D model in wpf. any related article's suggestions modt welcomed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127753/displaying-3d-models-in-wpf

Comment: @Ewan thanks for the response, I have gone through with that before itself. still, displaying a 3d model inside wpf is doesnt a matter, I can do that but how about controlling that with specific point is the question. the functionality in the 1st link in my question need to be added up in my project, for that I can't simply go with direct 3d addition, I hope I would go with XNA gaming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show a 3D model in WPF using view port, but for the kind of virtual dressing project to operate model with skeleton, that's better to go by XNA. Though we can connect with WPF, few operation like moving the hand of the product is difficult in WPF comparatively with XNA.