# Showing 3D model in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

I need to show a 3D model in WPF. I have my 3D Model created in .3ds, and .fbx extension. Now what i need to do is convert my existing 3D Model which is of .3ds and .fbx extension into XAML so that i can use it in WPF. My basic requirement is to show these 3D Models in WPF and perform animation on them. 
Could anyone please help me with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying 3D models in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127753/displaying-3d-models-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this program to convert from .3ds to XAML: http://www.ab4d.com/Viewer3ds.aspx

There are also various XAML exporter plugins, Blender for example: 
[Blender XAML Export Plugin](http://xamlexporter.codeplex.com/)