# Display 3D model's coordinates (position)

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, 3d-model

I have a 3D model in C# wpf that rotates 360degrees rotating 5degrees each time using timespan. But I want to be able to view its coordinates like viewing the point3DX, point3DY, point3DZ on my window form.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Here are the functions where I set the initial position and the rotation of the model

```
 private void SetViewPosition()
    {
        Vector3D vAxis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
        ///<summary>
        ///R = AxisAngleRotation()
        ///vAxis = Vector length
        ///-15 = Angle
        ///</summary>
        AxisAngleRotation3D myRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vAxis, -15);
        RotateTransform3D myRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(myRotation);
        gCamWC = myRotationTransform.Value;
        gCamWC.M14 = -50;
        gCamWC.M24 = 10;
        gCamWC.M34 = 0;

        Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14, gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
        Vector3D startLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);//VLook = 1st Column//DT=[1,0,0]//Vertical
        Vector3D startLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);//VUp = 2nd Column//DT = [0,0,1]//Vertical


        DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(camPosition, startLookAt, startLookUp, 0);//=DR -> How the camera should move

    }

    //STEP 4
   private void RotatingModelAround(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Vector3D vAxis = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M31, gCamWC.M32, gCamWC.M33);  //Rotate about world z-axis.
        AxisAngleRotation3D myRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vAxis, 5);
        RotateTransform3D myRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(myRotation);

        Matrix3D doTranslation = new Matrix3D();
        doTranslation.M24 = 3;  // Offset along camera y-axis.  Presumed to be parallel to world plane.


        gCamWC.Append(myRotationTransform.Value);
        gCamWC.Append(doTranslation);

        Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14, gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
        Vector3D camLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);
        Vector3D camLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);

        DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(camPosition, camLookAt, camLookUp, 0);
    }
```

And this is where they are called

```
   public XplorerMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closed += XplorerMainWindow_Closed;
        //STEP 1
        Loaded += XplorerMainWindow_Loaded;

        Closing += XplorerMainWindow_Closing;
        DrawingControl.UserModeledDimensionChangedEvent += DrawingControl_MeasureChangedEvent;
        InitFromSettings();

        RefreshRecentFiles();

        UserFilters = new FilterValues();//COBie Class filters, set to initial defaults
        CoBieTemplate = UkTemplate;


        if (Settings.Default.PluginStartupLoad)
            RefreshPlugins();




        //STEP 4
       // Add Dispatcer Time so the Rotation will be repeated
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += RotatingModelAround;
        //dispatcherTimer.Tick += QRotateModel;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0,300);//(d,h,m,s,mil.s.)
        dispatcherTimer.Start();


    }
```

For example according to my project, I want this part of my code:

```
Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14, gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
        Vector3D camLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);
        Vector3D camLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);
```

... to be displayed on my window form like:

**Camera Position: (-50.00, 10.00, 0.00)
Camera LookAt: (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)
Camera LookUp: (0.00, 0.00, 1.00)**

And every time the camera will rotate 5degrees, the changed values will be displayed on the window form

Comment: Code?  If you show us what you're using for the rotating and rendering we can more easily tailor a solution to your needs.  Also what have you tried?

Comment: My code is big, but I will only add the functions where I add the position and the rotation. I haven't tried anything because I couldn't find any examples

Comment: Well without any idea how you are rendering the model it's hard to say how you could get the values.  Can you say if you are using a specific library or kit or class or something?  Also relevant link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127753/displaying-3d-models-in-wpf

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I do rotate the model but what I want is to instead adding a breakpoint to my function and view the coordinates or position of the camera each time it moves, I want the coordinates to be displayed on my window form.

Comment: If my answer below does not work, can you comment with what happens (or doesn't happen) when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See update below in response to you clarifying your question a bit more :) )

Originally you said you wanted to know the coordinates of your 3d model.

> I have a 3D model in C# wpf that rotates 360degrees rotating 5degrees
>   each time using timespan. But I want to be able to view its
>   coordinates like viewing the point3DX, point3DY, point3DZ on my window
>   form.

However in a comment you clarified it was actually the camera location you were interested in.

> ... what I want is to ... view the coordinates or position of the
>   camera each time it moves, I want the coordinates to be displayed on
>   my window form.

Assuming the comment is your real question (How do I get and show the 3d position of my camera), here is my solution:

*gCamWC* is a [Matrix3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d.matrix3d(v=vs.110).aspx). I know this because:

```
gCamWC = myRotationTransform.Value;
```

..and since myRotationTransform is a RotateTransform3d, its value is a Matrix3D ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rotatetransform3d.value(v=vs.110).aspx)).

I am unfamiliar with Matrix3D's, but a quick MSDN search suggests you could just create a label (I'll call this posLabel) and in the RotatingModelAround method after you append gCamWC do this:

```
posLabel.Text = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}", gCamWC.offsetX, gCamWC.offsetY, gCamWC.offsetZ;
```

If it works, this should make the label say something like this (for an example of a vector of 3.0, 6.7, 8.9):

> 3.0     6.7       8.9

**(sorry SO formatting doesn't let me do tab spaces but there would be a tab between each of those values)*

And it should update every time it rotates.

**EDIT:**
You say you want a label like this:

> Camera Position: (-50.00, 10.00, 0.00) Camera LookAt: (1.00, 0.00,
>   0.00) Camera LookUp: (0.00, 0.00, 1.00)

Try creating a label called posLabel and then add the following code after you finish appending gCamWC in the RotatingModelAround() method:

```
posLabel.Text = "Camera Position: (" + gCamWC.M14 + ", " + gCamWC.M24 + ", " + gCamWC.M34 + ") Camera LookAt: (" + gCamWC.M11 + ", " + gCamWC.M21 + ", " + gCamWC.M31 + ") Camera LookUp: (" + gCamWC.M13 + ", " + gCamWC.M23 + ", " + gCamWC.M33 + ")";
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so Much, and sorry for the confusion about the model position and camera position, it is just sometimes I forgot that I work on the camera and not on the model, because it makes it look like you move the the model instead of the camera :)